Add segments to plot too slow
I would like to draw some line segments, I read this SO. it works fine if data number is small, say 20. but if the number incease to 100000, it almost stuck there.
Any suggestion to improve performance?
Code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

def save_fig(fig,pngname):
    fig.write_image(pngname,format="png",width=800,height=500, scale=1)
    print("[[%s]]"%pngname)
    return

def main():
    n = 1000000
    x = range(0,n)
    y0 = np.random.uniform(size = n)
    y1 = y0 + np.random.uniform(size = n) *4
    print(len(x),len(y0),len(y1))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y0':y0 , 'y1':y1 })
    x_range=range(1,len(df.index)+1)
    trace0 = go.Scatter(
        x=df['x'],
        y=df['y0'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(color='blue')
    )
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x=df['x'],
        y=df['y1'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(color='blue',size=1)
    )
    shapes=[dict(
        type='line',
        x0 = df['x'].loc[i],
        y0 = df['y0'].loc[i],
        x1 = df['x'].loc[i],
        y1 = df['y1'].loc[i],
        line = dict(
            color = 'black',
            width = 1
        )
    ) for i in range(len(df['x']))]
    layout = go.Layout(
        shapes = shapes,
        showlegend=False,
        title='demo'
    )
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(trace0)
    fig.add_trace(trace1)
    fig.update_layout(layout)
    save_fig(fig,'/media/sf_work/demo.png')
    return

main()



If the data size is large, consider Scattergl() instead of Scatter(). I changed your code to Scattergl() and ran 1,000,000. It may take a little longer, but the graph will be created. However, it does not use Shape. Refer this.
